# Silverlight 4 wait for ASync

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous, silverlight-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a silverlight 4 control in my Dynamics CRM.

I have it to create multiple opportunities based on whether or not it has multiple ship dates. Users have a simple form at the bottom of the opportunity create form with product information, dates and revenue.  This creates copy of the original with the alternate information that users entered in the control.

Currently it creates the opportunities as long as the user waits for a while for the calls to be completed; ideally I would like the form to close automatically after all the new opportunities have been created. Here is the relevant code; can anyone help me with what I need to add to have the CRM wait for everything to be created.

```
        //OpportunitySet contains all necessary information to create multiple records, 
        //data is valid(it will create information if enough time is given.
        _context.BeginSaveChanges(OnCreateOpportunityComplete, _context.OpportunitySet);
        xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_haschildren").setValue(true);
        xrm.Page.data.entity.save("saveandclose");

        private void OnCreateOpportunityComplete(IAsyncResult result)
        {
          try
          {
            _context.EndSaveChanges(result);
            Opportunity createdOpportunity = result.AsyncState as Opportunity;
            //result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
            MessagePanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock()
            {
              Text = String.Format("Created a new Opportunity named \"{0}\"\n\twith OpportunityId = \"{1}\".",
                    createdOpportunity.Name, createdOpportunity.OpportunityId)
            });

            BeginRetrieveOpportunity(createdOpportunity.OpportunityId);
            OnRetrieveOpportunityComplete(result);
          }
          catch (SystemException se)
          {
            _syncContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback(showErrorDetails), se);
          }
        }
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put the xrm save&close method as last row to be executed inside your complete method.

Comment: It is the last row in my main method; I've tried a few things for it to take more time to get to it but nothing seems to have worked yet.

Comment: if you have async methods before has no use to put the xrm method as last row inside the main, must be inside the last complete method of your async calls. You can also do a chain of the async calls (to simulate a synchronous behavior, for example on complete of the first async you call the second async and go on)

Comment: I've just tried that, and the form never closed; I put a breakpoint in OnCreateOpportunityComplete and nothing was ever hit even though the records were created.

Comment: just to be sure, you defined `dynamic xrm = (ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("Xrm");` together with your save&close method?

Comment: Thank you so much; just moved some things around, removed code that didnt have to be where it was and now it works. I've spent more time on this than I care to admit. Again thank you very much

Comment: Just an addition, the messagepanel stack command was crashing before it hit the save and close; thats why it didnt get there. I also removed async calls that i didnt need to retrieve the newly created opportunities for no reason.